# Routing rules for components in Altium

Tags: altium, routing

Is there a way to make a speciffic routing rule applicable only for selected components (or component class)?

I want to define some "routing width" rules that will start routing the same net (e.g. GND) with a wide tracks from components with wide pads and use thiner tracks for smaller components.

Is there a way to do that without defining some extra rooms around components?

Comment: Perhaps a neckdown rule will do? http://wiki.altium.com/display/ADOH/SMD+Neck-Down

Comment: That's not exactly what I was looking for. You can only limit the maximum track width with it. I wanted to do the oposite - define the minimal track width.

Comment: I think the way to resolve this is using from-to classes. Within it you can define connections between chosen components. However when I specify routing rule to the specific from-to class it doesn't seem to apply at all. Any ideas on how to make this work?

Answer (score 1):

With a PCB doc open, go to Design -> Rules, select Routing -> Width

Create a Query, such as:

```
inNet('GND') or inComponent('U1')
```

Alternately, you can use the Query Helper or Query Builder to set up your rule.